# Configuration of Mozilla Thunderbird without automatic guessing

Tags: thunderbird

When trying to configure new eMail accounts, Mozilla Thunderbird tries to *guess* at the server settings.  Unfortunately, this feature causes a lot of problems, particularly when the internet connection is down (or when trying to set up an account before the mail server is configured) which makes it impossible to set up the account at all.

How can I disable this "automatic guessing" functionality in Thunderbird when setting up a new eMail account?

Comment: *"Unfortunately, this feature causes a lot of problems..."*: +1. I call it a software torture device.

Answer (score 2):

You can start Thunderbird by calling:

```
thunderbird -ProfileManager
```

Then check the "**Work offline**" option. The wizard will start anyway, but you should be able to close it without later troubles.

Comment: Hopefully I can try tomorrow -- thank you; this seems to be a good solution.